# For document id same as user uid, how to retrieve only one user's data from firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am making an app using Dart, Flutter and Firebase. There is sign up/ login, and I am using cloud firestore as a database. In my cloud firestore, the user UID is the document id, and I have specific data(result) for each users.

I want to retrieve current user's data only (which is stored in the Firestore)and display on the screen.[This is my cloud firestore image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ0tT.png)

```
void submitit(double n, m) async {
final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
final String usr = user.uid.toString();
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
_formKey.currentState.save();
result = n * m;
}
DatabaseService(uid: usr).updateUserData(result.toString()); // to store data in firestore
//data is successfully stored in firestore.

//now retrive this user's result only from firestore
```

There are many users who have signed up and logged in.
Now I want to retrieve only this user's result from the cloud Firestore and display on the screen.
I need a generalised solution so that, whoever is the current user, that corresponding result is retrieved and displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the data of the currently logged in user, then you can do:

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async {
var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
return await Firestore.instance.collection("result").document(firebaseUser.uid).get();
}
```

Comment: Using this I get the value as {result: 98190.3},
Can you tell me, how can I get only the number out of it ???

Comment: please ask it as a different question with the code that u are using to display and link me here so i can check it